# I get a SyntaxError in "parse" when importing stumpy

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, stumpy

I am trying to import stumpy, but I'm always getting an a SyntaxError:

import stumpy

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in 
    import stumpy

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stumpy__init__.py", line 38, in 
    module = ast.parse(file_contents)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

File "unknown", line 29
    Î£_T,
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. Fixed in stumpy version 1.2.2 !